# Is a sufficient statistic for a parameter $\lambda$ in the exponential family also sufficient for the reciprocal of $\lambda$?

Tags: exponential-distribution, sufficient-statistics

If $\{E(\lambda)\}_{\lambda > 0}$ denotes the exponential family, then $E(\frac{1}{\theta}), \theta > 0$ is an alternative parameterization. I think a sufficient statistic for $\lambda$ is also sufficient for $\theta = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Do I prove this using contradiction? My thinking is if the statistic were not sufficient for $\theta$, then it wouldn't have been sufficient for $\lambda$ in the first place. If that's right, I'd like to answer my own question.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Neyman-Fisher factorization criterion?

Comment: Somewhat. Using 'factorization' in the sense of Neyman-Fisher, if the density with parameter $\theta$ doesn't factorize, then the density with parameter $\lambda$ wouldn't have factorized, which means that the statistic wouldn't have been sufficient for $\lambda$. Is this more on the right track?

Comment: Pretty much, but you don't need to use contradiction. If the original density factorized as $h(x) g(T(x), \theta)$, where $T$ is the sufficient statistic, then it also factorizes as $h(x) \tilde{g}(T(x), \lambda)$ where $\tilde{g}(T(x), \lambda) = g(T(x), 1/\lambda)$. Of course the same proof works as long as $\lambda$ is an injective function of $\theta$.